# This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed:

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex, lwc, lightning

```
'cmp file'

<aura:component >
    
    <aura:attribute name="aval" type="Integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name="bval" type="Integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name="result" type="Integer"/>
    
    
    <lightning:card title="Calculator" iconName ="standard:lead">
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:buttonGroup>
                <lightning:button label="Add" onclcik="{!c.Addme}"/>
                <lightning:button label="Subtract" onclick="{!c.Subme}" />
                <lightning:button label="multiply" onclick="{!c.Mulme}" />

            </lightning:buttonGroup>
        </aura:set> 
        
        
        <lightning:input label="enter the first NO" value="{!v.aval}"/>
        <lightning:input label="enter the second NO" value="{!v.bval}"/>
        <lightning:input label="result" value="{!v.result}"/>
        
   </lightning:card>
</aura:component>

SO basically the above one is my component code 

'Controller code :::::'
'''
({
    Addme : function(component) 
    {
        var A=Component.get("v.aval");
        var B=Component.get("v.bval");
        var C=a+b;
        console.log(c);
        Component.set("v.result",C);
    },
    Subme : function(component) 
    {
        var A=Component.get("v.aval");
        var B=Component.get("v.bval");
        var C=a-b;
        Component.set("v.result",C);
    },
     Mulme : function(component) 
    {
        var A=Component.get("v.aval");
        var B=Component.get("v.bval");
        var C=a*b;
        Component.set("v.result",c);
    }
   
})


here the above one is the controller code where i defined the fucntions for add,sub and mul


'application :'

<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <c:v5testing/>
</aura:application>
```

Here this is my application code where in im calling
on the whole it is simple add problem using attributes and input concept in lightning .

PLease help me out
I get error in this way -->
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:v5testing$controller$Addme [Component is not defined]
Failing descriptor: {c:v5testing$controller$Addme}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to be noted in your code that -

1. spelling of **onclick** is wrong you can correct it

   <lightning:button label="Add" onclcik="{!c.Addme}"/>
2. **Component** and **component** both are different as **javascript is case sensitive language** therefore it treats both variables different, so please make a sure correct case, lowercase, or uppercase for variables
3. Try to use **parseInt()** javascript method to convert the values into numbers/integers, to be on a safer side.

Below is your code, which I try to make it error-free

**Cmp File**

```
<aura:component >
    
    <aura:attribute name="aval" type="Integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name="bval" type="Integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name="result" type="Integer"/>
    
    
    <lightning:card title="Calculator" iconName ="standard:lead">
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:buttonGroup>
                <lightning:button label="Add" onclick="{!c.Addme}"/>
                <lightning:button label="Subtract" onclick="{!c.Subme}" />
                <lightning:button label="multiply" onclick="{!c.Mulme}" />

            </lightning:buttonGroup>
        </aura:set> 
        
        
        <lightning:input label="enter the first NO" value="{!v.aval}"/>
        <lightning:input label="enter the second NO" value="{!v.bval}"/>
        <lightning:input label="result" value="{!v.result}"/>
        
   </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

**JS File**

```
({
    Addme : function(component) 
    {
        var A=component.get("v.aval");
        var B=component.get("v.bval");
        var C=parseInt(A)+parseInt(B);
        console.log(C);
        component.set("v.result",C);
    },
    Subme : function(component) 
    {
        var A=component.get("v.aval");
        var B=component.get("v.bval");
        var C=parseInt(A)-parseInt(B);
        component.set("v.result",C);
    },
     Mulme : function(component) 
    {
        var A=component.get("v.aval");
        var B=component.get("v.bval");
        var C=parseInt(A)*parseInt(B);
        component.set("v.result",C);
    }
   
})
```

**App File**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <c:v5testing/>
</aura:application>
```

Please let me know if it help you out also mark it solved, if you like my answer.

Thanks.

Comment: It really solved my code . srry for updating it late . i am new to stackoverflow